# Oracle - Fastest way to update sequential rows based on previous rows value

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update

I have a table with Quantity and Remaining columns, and have to update all the rows in the table after ordering it over some date column.

Remaining column's value is calculated by (previous row's remaining) + or - (this row's quantity). I have written a cursor loop to achieve this task, but it's taking ages to finish.

```
OPEN KAL;
      LOOP
        FETCH KAL
          INTO V_PK_ID, V_TYPE_ID, V_QUANTITY;

        IF (V_TYPE_ID = 1) THEN
          V_REMAINING := V_REMAINING + V_QUANTITY;
        ELSE
          V_REMAINING := V_REMAINING - V_QUANTITY;
        END IF;

        UPDATE TABLE K
           SET K.REMAINING = V_REMAINING
         WHERE K.KALAMAZOO_ID = V_PK_ID;

      END LOOP;
CLOSE KAL;
```

Is there anything i can do to achieve this faster, or is there any other methods i can use to accomplish this?

**Edit: Sample Data**

```
PK  TYPE    QUANTITY    REMAINING
1   1       100         900
2   2       50          950
3   2       25          975
4   1       200         775
5   1       125         650
6   1       50          600
```

For example, if i start with "1000", Type 1 is for (-) and Type 2 is for (+), rows will be updated like above.

Comment: Please show sample table data and query

Comment: Where is the 1000 shown in your table? Or is it input in some other way?

Comment: Also, is that your base table structure, or are you doing this for a view? If it's for the base table, `remaining` should be a virtual column (https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1) - saving it as a stored column would violate elementary normalization principles.

Comment: @mathguy It cannot be virtual because is not derived from the same row. And if you are long in the database programming, you will now that  "violation elementary normalization principles" is not violation. Sometime you need denormalization.

Comment: @Mottor - ugh, you are right about the virtual column thing, not thinking straight. I understand the point about need to de-normalize, but when data is not in normal form, it is much more often without reason than with. As to being long in database programming - I am retired (early) from other businesses, interested in db programming just for volunteer work; I only ever wrote a SQL statement in February of this year for the first time... Just to clarify where I come from - and to explain the many rookie mistakes I make. Thanks!

Comment: I only wanted to mention it, not to insult you. It does not mater how long you in, but how many different type of tasks you have done. For sample denormalization is normal thing in data mining. Everyone is learning.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `merge`.  The logic is something like this:

```
merge into k
      using (select k.*,
                    sum(case when v_type_id = 1 then v_quantity else - v_quantity end) over
                        (order by v_pk_id) as new_remaining
             from k
            ) s
      on (k.v_pk_id = s.v_pk_id)
when matched then
    update set k.remaining = s.new_remaining;
```

A PL/SQL loop should not be necessary for the calculation.

Comment: @Mottor . . . I didn't reject any edits on this answer.